# Angular Unit Testing : Karma-Jasmine : ('onChange', (changeEvent: MatRadioChange) : Argument of type void is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Hi was working on one of the tests for a call that I am using to emit the event:

```
onChange(eventName: MatRadioChange): void {
    this.eventName.emit(eventName.value);
  }
```

The test for the same is:

```
describe('onChange', (eventName: MatRadioChange) => {
    it('should emit true to open calendar modal for mobile view', () => {
      spyOn(component.eventName, 'emit');
      component.onChange(eventName.value);
      expect(component.eventName.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Argument of type '(changeEvent: MatRadioChange) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'.

describe('onChange', (changeEvent: MatRadioChange) => {
```

Any help will be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a TypeScript issue. The issue is on this line:

```
component.onChange(eventName.value);
```

I assume `eventName.value` is a string and not `MatRadioChange`.

To get by this, do this:

```
component.onChange({ value: 'abc' } as any);
```

The `as any` casts the object to `any` type and it should suffice the `MatRadioChange` type.